# What am I - Forests but no trees

Tags: riddle

Riddle me this:

I have seas, but no water.

I have forests, but no trees/plants.

I have deserts, but no sand.

I have cities, but no buildings.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be a

> map

because

> a map has seas, forests, deserts, and cities, but does not have (literal) water, trees, sand, and buildings.